# How do I restore just one app's data with adb?

Tags: applications, adb, backup, restore

I used `adb backup -f DailyBeanBackup.ab com.bluesignum.bluediary` and it made a backup file and I want to try restoring it but when it asks for my password it says `This will replace any data currently on the device!` and I do not want to delete everything on my phone. Will it just replace the apps data and it's safe and if not is there way to restore just that?

Comment: That is just a misinterpretation of the message. "ANY" in the context of restoring one app means "any data of that app".